# Simple AngularJS, AJAX, and ASP.NET MVC example

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I would like to see an extremely minimalistic example of AngularJS making an AJAX call to an ASP.NET MVC action method. I have tried to do this myself with no success. Here is my example code...

The MVC action method...

```
public string Color()
{
    return "red";
}
```

The HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html ng-app ="ColorApp">
<head>
    <title>ColorApp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ColorController">
        {{color}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript...

```
var colorApp = angular.module('ColorApp', []);

colorApp.controller('ColorController', function ($scope) {

    $http({
        url: '/home/color',
        method: 'GET'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.color = data;
    });

});
```

Some things to consider:

- If I replace the `$http` method with something like `$scope.color = 'purple';` then my view renders the word "purple" as expected.
- If I leave everything as is but replace the AngularJS with jQuery, everything works as expected (I get "red").
- I tried changing `{{color}}` to `{{color()}}` but it made no difference.
- I tried changing the action method to a `JsonResult` and returning `Json("red", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` but this made no difference either.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add **$http**  to your controller

```
colorApp.controller('ColorController', function ($scope,$http) {
      $http({
                url: '/home/color',
                method: 'GET'
           }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.color = data;
     });
});
```

Comment: Wow! It's that simple. Thanks a ton! :)